# Why is the poison that came out of Samudra Manthana called Halahalam and Kaalakootam?

Tags: samudra-manthan

This question discusses how poison was the [first thing that came out of Samudra Manthana.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12244/what-was-the-first-object-that-came-out-of-samudra-manthana) Shiva drank that poison to save everyone and is known as Neelakantha. The poison itself is called हलाहलं (Halahalam) or कालकूटं (KaalaKootam).

I heard that the word हलाहलं is mentioned in different forms in different texts.

Also, this wiki article describes (maybe not correctly) two of the [meanings of KaalaKootam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halahala) as 'black mass' or 'time puzzle'.

Why is the poison given these two names - हलाहलं and कालकूटं ? Is there any hidden symbolism behind it?

Comment: Maybe you can ask about the different pronunciations as well.

Comment: I can give an interpretation though I don't know whether it is right - Halahala is that which makes the world cry out 'Hala Hala' in terror.

Comment: Or maybe if you split it as Hala-Ahala then it can mean that which undoes the fabric (literally vowels) of the universe.

Comment: @Surya Done....

Comment: I think Sagara Madanam is alluding to something. Many people provide different interpretations.  See [this answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-underlying-symbolism-of-the-Samudra-Manthan/answer/Abhishek-Khanna-33) on Quora.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thats interesting. It can also be seen as the churning of the life of a person.

Answer (score 4):

The Amarakosha gives the names Kalakuta and Halahala to the poison of the Nagas in Bhogivarga or The Section about Snakes.

The **Amarapadavivrtti** Commentary By Lingayasuri gives the following meanings:

Kalakoota:

- Kalavarnasya Kootah Iti - The poison (fumes) that is black in colour
- Kalam Yamam Api Kootayati Iti Va - That which burns even Yama, the god of Death

Halahalam:

- Halati Vilikhati Jatharam Na Halati Cha - That which ploughs and twists the stomach while simultaneously straightening it (in short, torturing and re-torturing a person)

The **Amarapadaparijata** of Mallinatha says the following:

Halahalam:

- Hrdaye Halahalam Mahad Visham - Halahala is a toxic poison to the heart (implying that it can cause instant death)

Comment: What are these two works, works on Nirukta or what?

Comment: @Keshav Both are commentaries to Amarakosha the Sanskrit Lexicon.

Comment: So is the Amarakosha a work in the Nirukta genre or something else?

Comment: @Keshav No the Amarakosha is the Sanskrit Thesaurus which is accepted by all Sanskrit scholars as the definitive thesaurus.